# Google Email Migration API v2: Not possible to migrate directly to All Mail Archive in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I'm testing out the [newly announced](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/07/introducing-new-version-of-email.html) Google Email Migration API v2. I haven't found any way to migrate an email message directly to the "All Mail" folder (archived in Gmail). In other words, to not put any labels or Inbox on the message. It seems like this would be possible with a request like:

```
POST /upload/email/v2/users/admin@jay.powerposters.org/mail?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 402
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary="part_boundary"
Authorization: Bearer <removed>
--part_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
 'isInbox': 'false'
}

--part_boundary
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2013 02:56:03 -0800
From: admin@example.org
To: liz@example.com
Subject: Hello World!
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit

And I think to myself... What a wonderful world!

--part_boundary--
```

but this message still gets placed in the Inbox. Am I missing some other way to not apply a label to a message and not put it Inbox or is this a bug?